# How to do a DLOOKUP

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to do a DLOOKUP but not sure where I am going wrong.

- I have a table header of the date, in my example: 04/04/16
- I have a table called tblMasterLeagueAvailability
- I have a textbox called text2 with the individuals name in it

  `=DLookUp("04/04/16","tblMasterLeagueAvailability","[Name] =  [Text2] ")`

The formula above is not working.

I want it to lookup the table header 04/04/16 in tblMasterLeagueAvailability and show the results for the persons name in text2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The textbox reference must be outside the string. Try something like

```
=DLookUp("04/04/16","tblMasterLeagueAvailability", 
         "[Name] = '" & Replace(Forms!myForm![Text2], "'", "''") & "'")
```

You need the single quotes `'` for filtering text fields.

The `Replace()` is there to prevent an error when `[Text2]` contains a `'` itself.

---

Note: a column name "04/04/16" indicates a problematic table design.

Comment: Thank you for this - Its definitely retuning some results, but its showing the stats for the wrong agent. Cant get my head around that.